# Is there a way to list all additions (ever) in a Git project?

Tags: git, github, bitbucket

Sometimes at the end of a project I think to myself "Wow, I just wrote a ton of lines of code for that project." But I never know just how much.

Is there any way to actually list *all* of the added lines of code to the repo since its creation?

I think that sort of thing would be fascinating to look at.

EDIT:
I also think it would be cool if there was some way to save all of the lines of code that I've written into a single monstrous txt file--just for the sake of looking at it. Is that possible?

Comment: You just want to see all the lines that were added?  That is just using `wc` on your code base.  Or are you looking for more specific stats?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"all the added lines of code to the repo" is basically all the code currently in the repo.

Now, if you want to see how much code *you* added to the repo, you can get a summary by runing e.g.

```
git log --author 'Yourself' --patch | diffstat
```

To see all the lines you have added (i.e. all those which appear with a leading `+` in one of the patches), you can run

```
git log --author 'Yourself' --patch | grep -v '^\+\+\+ ' | grep '^\+' | sed 's/^\+//' >my-added-lines.txt
```

and read `my-added-lines.txt`.

For more detailed information (graph of who added what at what point in time, ...), have a look at the [gitstats](http://gitstats.sourceforge.net/) tool.

**edit**: added a way to see all added lines.

Comment: Sweet! Is there a way to save to a file? See my edit.

Comment: You could always redirect the standard output of the command to a file by adding `> filename`.